# Comparing two drawables in android

Tags: android

How to compare two drawables, I am doing like this but not having any success

```
public void MyClick(View view)
{
 Drawable fDraw = view.getBackground();
 Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

  if(fDraw.equals(sDraw))
  {
   //Not coming
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463737/compatibility-of-getcontext-and-getresource-between-5-0-and-lower

Comment: If you are writing tests with Robolectric and the goal is to determine if the correct drawable was loaded, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008044/assert-imageview-was-loaded-with-specific-drawable-resource-id

Answer (score 150, accepted):

**Update**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36373569/1835650

**getConstantState() works not well**

<s>There is another way to compare:</s>

```
mRememberPwd.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
            (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_checked).getConstantState());
```

`mRemeberPwd` is an `ImageView` in this example. If you're using a `TextView`, use `getBackground().getConstantState` instead.

Comment: This solution works and its better as it avoids converting Drawable into Bitmap and compare.

Comment: Not always: WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).getFastDrawable().getConstantState() is null.

Comment: Sorry for late accepting this as answer and changing my own answer as this seems better option (and more upvotes also :) ). So checking this as answer.

Comment: This code works great on devices lower than 5.0 but im getting errors using it on a 5.0 device, can anyone confirm this method works or not on android 5.0 or higher

Comment: This will not work in Android 5.0 and higher. You should never rely on constant state equality.

Comment: Did you got any solution for 5.0 version?

Comment: Any solution for SDK 21+?

Comment: have you got any solution for 5.0 for comparing drawables ?

Comment: Else we can do it by imageView.getBackground().getConstantState.equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.resource_id).getConstantState())

Comment: this method is crashing the app on android v5.1.1, any alternatives?

Comment: It works not well with vector, the update is for generic cases.

Comment: "Calling Drawable#mutate() on a Drawable should typically create a new ConstantState for that Drawable." What about those non-typical cases? This answer is a flaky hack.

Answer (score 45):

Relying on `getConstantState()` alone can result in [false negatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives#False_negative_error).

The approach I've taken is to try comparing the ConstantState in the first instance, but fall back on a Bitmap comparison if that check fails.

This should work in all cases (including images which aren't resources) but **note that it is memory hungry.**

```
public static boolean areDrawablesIdentical(Drawable drawableA, Drawable drawableB) {
    Drawable.ConstantState stateA = drawableA.getConstantState();
    Drawable.ConstantState stateB = drawableB.getConstantState();
    // If the constant state is identical, they are using the same drawable resource.
    // However, the opposite is not necessarily true.
    return (stateA != null && stateB != null && stateA.equals(stateB))
            || getBitmap(drawableA).sameAs(getBitmap(drawableB));
}

public static Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap result;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        result = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else {
        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        // Some drawables have no intrinsic width - e.g. solid colours.
        if (width <= 0) {
            width = 1;
        }
        if (height <= 0) {
            height = 1;
        }

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is 100% true and needs more upvotes! People, please test your code with known Drawables before immediately relying on `getConstantState()` comparison

Comment: Good findings! But according to the documentation of BitmapDrawable.getBitmap(), getBitmap() may be null so you might want to check this as well

Comment: This answer is true and I have checked that after debugging several hours with the coding of only getConstantState().

Comment: To be safe, `setBounds` and `draw` on a copy instead of the original https://stackoverflow.com/a/25462223/1916449

Comment: This doesn't work with tinted BitmapDrawables (see setTintMode / setTint / setTintList). The bitmaps can be identical byte for byte but with different tint properties. Because the Android SDK does not provide any getters for the tint properties, there may not be a way to make it work with tinted drawables.

Comment: The docs say "Calling Drawable#mutate() on a Drawable should typically create a new ConstantState for that Drawable." In the non-typical cases, you will get a false positive.

Answer (score 15):

My question was for just comparing two drawables, I tried but could not get any method that directly compare two drawables,however for my solution i changed drawable to bitmap and then comparing two bitmaps and that is working.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)fDraw).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)sDraw).getBitmap();

if(bitmap == bitmap2)
    {
        //Code blcok
    }
```

Comment: thats what I was suggesting you, to compare drawable according to type of drawable.

Comment: You might also want to compare bitmaps like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696320/317889

Comment: This is very heavy, so consider recycling Bitmaps or you will end up in a OutOfMemoryError!

Comment: Why can you compare Bitmaps with pointer equality (==)?  I'd expect Bitmap.equals() to be needed.

Comment: @espertus You are right. I used same in question for drawable objects dont know why turned to == for bitmap object in answer. Any ways thanks for pointing out this basic.

Comment: @espertus Can you tell, which would be prefer here as both == and .equals working here.

Comment: @espertus Because == seems cheaper than .equals

Comment: == tests that the same object is returned; .equals() generally detects that the two values have the same hash code, although it is sometimes overridden in implementations.  They may be equivalent in this case -- I don't know -- but they shouldn't be assumed to be in every case.

In any case, I'm glad you found something that works for the case you need.

Answer (score 10):

for SDK 21+

this works in SDK -21

```
mRememberPwd.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
        (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_checked).getConstantState())
```

for SDK +21 android 5. 
set drawable id to imageview with tag

```
img.setTag(R.drawable.xxx);
```

and compare like this

```
if ((Integer) img.getTag() == R.drawable.xxx)
{
....your code
}
```

this solution is for who want to compare `drawable` id of `imageview` with  id of `drawable.xxx`.

Comment: Actually this works but I'm kind of shocked why there is no other possibility T_T!

Answer (score 4):

perhaps try it in this way:

```
public void MyClick(View view)
{
 Drawable fDraw = view.getBackground();
 Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

  if(fDraw.hashCode() == sDraw.hashCode())
  {
   //Not coming
  }
}
```

or prepare a method which takes two drawable arguments and return boolean. In that method you may convert drawable into bytes and compare,

```
public boolean compareDrawable(Drawable d1, Drawable d2){
    try{
        Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
        stream1.flush();
        byte[] bitmapdata1 = stream1.toByteArray();
        stream1.close();

        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)d2).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream2);
        stream2.flush();
        byte[] bitmapdata2 = stream2.toByteArray();
        stream2.close();

        return bitmapdata1.equals(bitmapdata2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: check the updated answer. if still doesn't work then check your drawables. Or try passing same drawables to verify the functionality of code

Comment: yes, after not getting success I am thinking same for converting drawables to bitmap and then to byte,let me try that one,thank you for your efforts

Comment: not working,did you test it? might be there is something wrong,cant we directly compare two drawables?

Comment: did you try it passing same drawable for `e.g R.drawable.abc` as both parameters?

Comment: hello waqas,check your method once again and then tell again whether it is working or not,might be possible that I am doing something wrong but that did not work,but then it changes definition of my question that how to compare two drawables.Changing drawable to bitmap and then bytes will then compare bitmap and bytes thats not my requirement.if we check drawable methods then there is method .equals(object) so I thought it should work directly,but it did not.Well you can check my answer below I am converting drawable to bitmap and then comparing two bitmaps and it is working.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for Android 5:

```
 if(image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(image.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.something).getConstantState()))
```

Answer (score 3):

**getDrawable(int)** is Now Deprecated. Use  **getDrawable(context,R.drawable.yourimageid)**

To Compare Two Backgrounds

```
Boolean Condition1=v.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.***).getConstantState());
```

Comment: This worked like a charm to fix an odd bug on Android 5. In my code, the actual drawable was returned with `context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.***)` on Android 6+ but wasn't on Android 5. With this little change I can compare background drawables across all Android versions flawlessly

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I've found the ultimate solution for this. Because of AppCompat and friends, the drawable provided is sometimes inflated in different forms so it's not enough to do `getResources().getBitmap(R.drawable.my_awesome_drawable)`.

So, in order to get a drawable instance of the same type and form as provided by the view one can do this:

```
public static Drawable drawableFrom(View view, @DrawableRes int drawableId) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    try {
        View dummyView = view.getClass().getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context);
        dummyView.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
        return dummyView.getBackground();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), drawableId, null);
    }
}
```

This is useful when doing tests. However, I would not recommend doing this in production. If you need to, extra caching would be desirable to avoid doing too much reflection.

For Expresso tests you can use this quite nicely:

```
onView(withDrawable(R.drawable.awesome_drawable))
  .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

or

```
onView(withId(R.id.view_id))
  .check(matches(withDrawable(R.drawable.awesome_drawable)));
```

Before you'll have to declare this helper class:

```
public class CustomMatchers {

  public static Matcher<View> withDrawable(@DrawableRes final int drawableId) {
     return new DrawableViewMatcher(drawableId);
  }
  private static class DrawableViewMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {

     private final int expectedId;
     private String resourceName;

     private enum DrawableExtractionPolicy {
        IMAGE_VIEW {
          @Override
          Drawable findDrawable(View view) {
             return view instanceof ImageView ? ((ImageView) view).getDrawable() : null;
          }
        },
        TEXT_VIEW_COMPOUND {
          @Override
          Drawable findDrawable(View view) {
             return view instanceof TextView ? findFirstCompoundDrawable((TextView) view) : null;
          }
        },
        BACKGROUND {
          @Override
          Drawable findDrawable(View view) {
             return view.getBackground();
          }
        };

        @Nullable
        private static Drawable findFirstCompoundDrawable(TextView view) {
          for (Drawable drawable : view.getCompoundDrawables()) {
             if (drawable != null) {
                return drawable;
             }
          }
          return null;
        }

        abstract Drawable findDrawable(View view);

     }

     private DrawableViewMatcher(@DrawableRes int expectedId) {
        this.expectedId = expectedId;
     }

     @Override
     protected boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
        resourceName = resources(view).getResourceName(expectedId);
        return haveSameState(actualDrawable(view), expectedDrawable(view));
     }

     private boolean haveSameState(Drawable actual, Drawable expected) {
        return actual != null && expected != null && areEqual(expected.getConstantState(), actual.getConstantState());
     }

     private Drawable actualDrawable(View view) {
        for (DrawableExtractionPolicy policy : DrawableExtractionPolicy.values()) {
          Drawable drawable = policy.findDrawable(view);
          if (drawable != null) {
             return drawable;
          }
        }
        return null;
     }

     private boolean areEqual(Object first, Object second) {
        return first == null ? second == null : first.equals(second);
     }

     private Drawable expectedDrawable(View view) {
        return drawableFrom(view, expectedId);
     }

     private static Drawable drawableFrom(View view, @DrawableRes int drawableId) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        try {
          View dummyView = view.getClass().getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context);
          dummyView.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
          return dummyView.getBackground();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), drawableId, null);
        }
     }

     @NonNull
     private Resources resources(View view) {
        return view.getContext().getResources();
     }

     @Override
     public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ");
        description.appendValue(expectedId);
        if (resourceName != null) {
          description.appendValueList("[", "", "]", resourceName);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare 2 drawable:

```
drawable1.constantState == drawable2.constantState
            || drawable1.toBitmap().sameAs(drawable2.toBitmap())
```

If you can not find `Drawable.toBitmap(...)` here is it [Drawable.kt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/Drawable.kt)

Comment: sdk 31, im using this `toBitmap().sameAs` to compare checkbox checked or unchecked based on two drawables..

Answer (score 2):

> Use getTag() and setTag() for comparison

Answer (score 0):

I already answered on the similar topic here: [Get the ID of a drawable in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407083/5524413).
The approach is based on tagging a view with a specified resource id in the custom `LayoutInflater`. Whole process is automated by a simple library [TagView](https://github.com/shuhart/TagView).

As a result, you can compare two drawables just by their ids:

```
TagViewUtils.getTag(view, ViewTag.VIEW_BACKGROUND.id) == R.drawable.twt_hover
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from @vaughandroid the following Matcher works for a Vector Drawable that is tinted. You have to provide the tint that was used for the Drawable.

```
public static Matcher<View> compareVectorDrawables(final int imageId, final int tintId) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
            if (!(target instanceof ImageView)) {
                return false;
            }
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) target;
            if (imageId < 0) {
                return imageView.getDrawable() == null;
            }
            Resources resources = target.getContext().getResources();
            Drawable expectedDrawable = resources.getDrawable(imageId, null);
            if (expectedDrawable == null) {
                return false;
            }

            Drawable imageDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            ColorFilter imageColorFilter = imageDrawable.getColorFilter();

            expectedDrawable.setColorFilter(imageColorFilter);
            expectedDrawable.setTintList(target.getResources()
                    .getColorStateList(tintId, null));

            boolean areSame = areDrawablesIdentical(imageDrawable, expectedDrawable);
            return areSame;
        }

        public boolean areDrawablesIdentical(Drawable drawableA, Drawable drawableB) {
            Drawable.ConstantState stateA = drawableA.getConstantState();
            Drawable.ConstantState stateB = drawableB.getConstantState();
            // If the constant state is identical, they are using the same drawable resource.
            // However, the opposite is not necessarily true.
            return (stateA != null && stateB != null && stateA.equals(stateB))
                    || getBitmap(drawableA).sameAs(getBitmap(drawableB));
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
            Bitmap result;
            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                result = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            } else {
                int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                // Some drawables have no intrinsic width - e.g. solid colours.
                if (width <= 0) {
                    width = 1;
                }
                if (height <= 0) {
                    height = 1;
                }

                result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                drawable.draw(canvas);
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a usefull method collected from GitHub copilot:

```
fun compareTwoDrawable(drawable1: Drawable, drawable2: Drawable): Boolean {
   val bitmap1 = (drawable1 as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
   val bitmap2 = (drawable2 as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
   return bitmap1.sameAs(bitmap2)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if You want to directly compare two drawable then use following code

Drawable fDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

```
if (fDraw.getConstantState().equals(sDraw.getConstantState())) {
    //write your code.
} else {
    //write your code.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are using `equals()` method it is used to compare the contents. you should try `==` for comparing two objects.

```
public void MyClick(View view)
{
 Drawable fDraw = view.getBackground();
 Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover);

  if( fDraw == sDraw )
  {
   // Coming
  }
}
```

Comment: then it may be possible that they are not ==, they are !=

Comment: but they refer to same image from resources

Comment: I just need to check whether they are equal or not?not any method available for that?

Comment: ya, i got your requirement, please come to chat room

Comment: == Compares if this is the same object, which it isn't n 99.99999999% of the time.