# Deep copy of a Drawable

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have an ImageView. In its onClick I get its Drawable:

```
Drawable dr = ((ImageView) v).getDrawable();
```

And set it to a dialog's ImageView:

```
zoomedImage.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

But when I close the dialog or the activity is resumed. The image at the original position gets stretched and is shown larger than its size, leading to only a portion of the image is visible in the ImageView.

Is this a case of deep copy or there is another problem?
If it is, how can do I deep copy the original Drawable so that I could set the copy to zoomed image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Finally I succeed!
I had similar problem, when I used color filter on my drawable it changed the drawable, its very close to the solution of the other people here, but only this worked for me:

```
Drawable drwNewCopy = dr.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();
```

Comment: FINALLY! This is the solution to create an autonomous copy of a drawable. To mutate() the orginal drawable is not a good solution, it does not always work. Creating a new copy from the cache of the drawable (i.e. the getContantState()) works. This comment FYI for others that have spent hours upon hours on this immature/nonfinished api.

Comment: extension for Kotlin :
fun Drawable.copy() = constantState?.newDrawable()?.mutate()

Comment: If I use the same `Drawable` on many views, is it better to copy like that or to get it again from resource?

Answer (score 22):

I managed to copy the drawable using following code:

```
drawable.mutate().getConstantState().newDrawable();
```

Here `mutate()` makes the drawable mutable to avoid sharing its state, and `getConstantState().newDrawable()` creates a new copy.

Thus different `ImageView`s use different drawables and there's no stretching.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to convert the drawable into bitmap separately  make or perform changes on it.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions won't work for me, But it works

```
val myDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(view.background).mutate() as GradientDrawable
myDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context, R.color.White))
```