# Osmdroid draw two or more diffrent markers

Tags: android, marker, osmdroid

I have a problem with Marker class from osmdorid. I try draw two markers with diffrent colors (blue and green), but i always got two markers with last color. It's any solution to do two or more markers each in a different color?

```
        //first marker
        Drawable mDrawable =  c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_white);
        mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ShapeColour.getInstance(c).paintFillColour().getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(51.119274, 10.326806);

        Marker osmMarker = new Marker(map.getMapView(), c);
        osmMarker.setPosition(point);
        osmMarker.setIcon(mDrawable);

        map.getMapView().getOverlays().add(osmMarker);

        //second marker
        Drawable mDrawable2 =  c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_white);
        mDrawable2.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51.117160, 10.315825);

        Marker osmMarker2 = new Marker(map.getMapView(), c);
        osmMarker2.setPosition(point2);
        osmMarker2.setIcon(mDrawable2);


        map.getMapView().getOverlays().add(osmMarker2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because ultimately, your code is changing twice the same object:

```
c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_white);
```

, no matter if through mDrawable or mDrawable2.

Solution: use 2 deep copies:

```
mD1 = mDrawable.mutate(); mD2 = mDrawable.mutate();
```

[Deep copy of a Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064473/deep-copy-of-a-drawable)