# android get the drawable that has sett as drawabletop of textview

Tags: android, textview

i have textview

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/new" />
```

and i want on activity jave to know which image has set on `drawableTop`, how ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use

```
 Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
```

Also if you want to compare two drawable.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawables[1] ).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover)).getBitmap();

if(bitmap == bitmap2)
    {
        //Code blcok
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good way to make the app create two bitmaps and compare them for each click on a TextView, right?

Comment: probably right, but I found this answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android

Comment: getCompoundDrawables() returns them in the specified order Left, Top, Right, Bottom

Answer (score 12):

First, give your `TextView` an ID so you can find it in your `Activity`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/new" />
```

Second, in your `Activity` find your `TextView` and get the compound drawables in your `onCreate` method after calling `setContentView`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
// Left, top, right, bottom drawables.
Drawable[] compoundDrawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
// This is the top drawable.
Drawable topCompoundDrawable = compoundDrawables[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use textView.getCompoundDrawables(); As for getting from drawable top i would think it would be the second drawable eg

```
Drawables tmp[] = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
tmp[1];  //this should be your top drawable but not 100% sure.
```

Comment: you changed the question )

Answer (score 2):

You cant get drawable ID in runtime. TextView uses ID only in it's constructor to load corresponding drawable. After drawable is loaded ID is gone.

In some cases there is no drawable ID at all. drawableTop can be a color rgb value.

Comment: An RGB value becomes a `ColorDrawable`