# How do I use .equals properly for this?

Tags: android, string

So here is my code,

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private long lastClick;

public int d = 0;
public int color;
TextView tv;
public int score;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            createSprites();
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int arg2, int height) {
        }

    });

}

private void createSprites() {

    int c = 10;
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256));
        for (int b = 1; b <= c; b++) {

            int random = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 24);
            if (random == 1) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad1));
            } else if (random == 2) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad2));
            } else if (random == 3) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad3));
            } else if (random == 4) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad4));
            } else if (random == 5) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad5));
            } else if (random == 6) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad6));
            } else if (random == 7) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad7));
            } else if (random == 8) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad8));
            } else if (random == 9) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad9));
            } else if (random == 10) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad10));
            } else if (random == 11) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad11));
            } else if (random == 12) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad12));
            } else if (random == 13) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad13));
            } else if (random == 14) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad14));
            } else if (random == 15) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad15));
            } else if (random == 16) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad16));
            } else if (random == 17) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad17));
            } else if (random == 18) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good1));
            } else if (random == 19) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good2));
            } else if (random == 20) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good3));
            } else if (random == 21) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good4));
            } else if (random == 22) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good5));
            } else if (random == 23) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good6));
            } else if (random == 24) {
                sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good7));
            }
        }

    }
}

private Sprite createSprite(int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    return new Sprite(this, bmp);

}

@SuppressLint({ "WrongCall", "DrawAllocation" })
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(color);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawText("SCORE  " + score, 10, 10, paint);

    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}

// this is the ontouch event to destroy the sprites and make the blood splat
// effect
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 200) {
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);

                if (sprite.isCollition(x, y)) {
                    {
                        if ((sprites).equals    (R.drawable.bad1))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad2))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad3))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad4))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad5))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad6))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad7))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad8))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad9))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad10))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad11))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad12))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad13))
                            score = score + 5;
                        else
                            score = score - 5;
                    }
                    d++;
                    if (d >= 10) {
                        d = 0;
                        createSprites();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

What I am trying to do is get,

```
   if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad1))
score = score + 5;
```

To check to see if somewhere in this code,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 200) {
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
```

Holds the value of one of the pics that are being deleted, but I am not sure how to code this properly. I am not sure if I need to place the pics into an array each time the randomizer runs or what but the code is taken from the "edu4java" tutorial from youtube.

I have the program on a loop as you can tell that I can delete the pics on touch and the score was right I just am not sure how to get the,

```
if ((sprites).equals(R.drawable.bad1))
score = score + 5;
```

To check to "see" the proper pic string. Do I need to check the array that the code "auto creates"? Is there a way to check and see what the value of a string is? Such as "seeing" what is actually being "held" by "sprite" or "sprites" ?

Comment: i think you want to use "contains" instead of "equals"

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you do not supply the source code for `Sprite`, but perhaps it [looks like the code here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14351)? Given the code there, there is no neat solution to your problem with the class as it is.

So, how I would approach solving this problem is to add to each sprite a resource ID:

```
private Sprite createSprite(int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    return new Sprite(this, bmp, resource);
}
```

Note that I add the extra `resource` parameter to the constructor. Furthermore, I would add to the `Sprite` class a method `int Sprite.getResource()`, so your collision detection code becomes:

```
if (sprite.isCollition(x, y))
{
    if (sprite.getResource() == R.drawable.bad1)
        score = score + 5;
    else if (sprite.getResource() == R.drawable.bad2)
        score = score + 5;
    else ...
}
```

Note: this code is in no way optimal, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction to discover for yourself a better solution. Here in Stack Overflow we don't throw fishes, we teach people to fish.

Comment: i know you don't :) .......and i have tried something like that .... because there is a sprite class but it isn't like what you have .....thank you .....i will give this a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a bitmap with a resource Id, and actually trying to do it manually your self would end up in quiet exhaustive performance for a simple validation, what i would do and to keep it simple, i would create my own class that extends from Sprite, and in stead of passing the context and bitmap, i would pass the context and resource Id, then within this class i would decode the resource and keep a reference of the resource id, i would override the equal method from Sprites and use the reference used to create the object to do the comparison, this would be my class

```
public class MySprite extends Sprite{
    private int bmpID;
    public MySprite(Context context, int bmpID){
        this.bmpID = bmpID;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), bmpID);
        super(context, bmp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof MySprite))return false;
        return this.bmpID == MySprite.class.cast(o).getBmpId();
    }

    public int getBmpId(){
        return bmpID;
    }
}
```

This way i keep it as a simple int comparison, and most important you can use it to compare two objects of same bmpID, or something like what u wanted by doing this:

```
if ((sprites).getBmpId() == R.drawable.bad1))
score = score + 5;
```

Regards!

Comment: this looks like it would be a more optimal solution ...... i have a LOT to learn lol ......thank you i will see how this goes as well .......THANK YOU ALL for helping me :)

Comment: If you liked any of the answers, i recommend you to mark one of them as correct, other way for further questions people might not answer your questions because of a low answers marked rate...