# Assert ImageView was loaded with specific drawable resource ID

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm writing a [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/) unit test and I need to make an assertion that an ImageView had [setImageResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) called on it with a certain resource ID. I'm using [fest-android](https://github.com/square/fest-android) for assertions but it doesn't appear to contain this assertion.

I also tried to get the [ShadowImageView](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowImageView.java) from Robolectric for the ImageView because I know it used to give you access to this, but it's now gone.

Lastly, I tried to call setImageDrawable in my code instead of setImageResource, then in my test assert like this:

```
assertThat(imageView).hasDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable));
```

but this also fails, even though the failure message clearly shows it's the same Drawable being loaded.

Answer (score 35):

### For Background

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
assertEquals(R.drawable.expected, Robolectric.shadowOf(imageView.getBackground()).getCreatedFromResId());
```

### For Drawable

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
assertEquals(R.drawable.expected, Robolectric.shadowOf(imageView.getDrawable()).getCreatedFromResId());
```

Comment: In robolectric 2.4 the method is `getImageResourceId()`

Answer (score 23):

From Roboelectric 3.0+

This is how you can do:

```
int drawableResId = Shadows.shadowOf(errorImageView.getDrawable()).getCreatedFromResId();
assertThat("error image drawable", R.drawable.ic_sentiment_dissatisfied_white_144dp, is(equalTo(drawableResId)));
```

Answer (score 6):

I ended up extending fest-android to solve this:

```
public class CustomImageViewAssert extends ImageViewAssert {

    protected CustomImageViewAssert(ImageView actual) {
        super(actual);
    }

    public CustomImageViewAssert hasDrawableWithId(int resId) {
        boolean hasDrawable = hasDrawableResourceId(actual.getDrawable(), resId);
        String errorMessage = String.format("Expected ImageView to have drawable with id <%d>", resId);
        Assertions.assertThat(hasDrawable).overridingErrorMessage(errorMessage).isTrue();
        return this;
    }

    private static boolean hasDrawableResourceId(Drawable drawable, int expectedResId) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        ShadowBitmap shadowBitmap = (ShadowBitmap) shadowOf(bitmap);
        int loadedFromResourceId = shadowBitmap.getCreatedFromResId();
        return expectedResId == loadedFromResourceId;
    }
}
```

The magic sauce is:

```
ShadowBitmap shadowBitmap = (ShadowBitmap) shadowOf(bitmap);
int loadedFromResourceId = shadowBitmap.getCreatedFromResId();
```

which is Robolectric specific, so I can't submit a pull request to fest-android with this.

Answer (score 1):

With kotlin extensions:

```
fun ImageView.hasDrawable(resId: Int): Boolean =
    Shadows.shadowOf(this.drawable).createdFromResId == resId

fun ImageView.hasBackground(resId: Int): Boolean =
    Shadows.shadowOf(this.background).createdFromResId == resId
```

Usage:

```
assertTrue(image.hasDrawable(R.drawable.image_resource))
```