# Verifying ImageView resource ID during testing

Tags: robotium, android-testing

I find that testing in Android is still complicated. It's not as easy as in JVM and also the framework is IMHO not testing friendly.

I have problem in testing, which is verifying the final resource ID of an ImageView. I'm only using Robotium. I'm not using fest-android. So the problem is different with [Assert ImageView was loaded with specific drawable resource ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008044/assert-imageview-was-loaded-with-specific-drawable-resource-id)

I tried to do the following, but failed

```
ImageView v = new ImageView(getActivity());
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_noart);


assertEquals(v.getDrawable(), 
    ((ImageView) solo.getView(R.id.image_album)).getDrawable());
```

Thanks