# get drawable from Android Menu Item Icon

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-menu

I have a bookmark icon in a menu item. I want to change the drawable in the icon depending on whether the bookmark has been pressed before or not.

I have two drawbles, staro (meaning star orange) or starw(meaning star white). I just want to toggle this on press.

How can I know which drawble is in the icon in `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method. Is it possible to know the drawable via the item. what I know is that item.getIcon() is not the drawble. I cannot compare `item.getIcon()` with `R.drawable.starto`

Comment: use shared pref. for remember  bookmark has been pressed before or not according to it change your drawable

Comment: yes, this was the second option i would chose, so, is it not possible to get the drawble from the menu item

Comment: but no need to store drawable into shared pref. store Boolean that is pressed or not and change according to it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try

```
if (item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.starto).getConstantState()
)) {
    ...
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android)

Comment: This works fine in api level 19 and lower but not in higher api.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the changes in onPrepareOptionsMenu() which is called every time before the menu is shown. Its suitable to show/hide options based on some dynamic data.

If you already now the condition, you can directly call

```
if (condition_for_orange) {
  menu.findItem(resourceId).setIcon(R.drawable.staro);
} else {
  menu.findItem(resourceId).setIcon(R.drawable.startw);
}
```

You can use Shared Preference or some other global variable which can store the state which may help you to decide which icon to show now.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare these too.

you can find id of drawable by

```
int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier("pic1", "drawable","android.demo");
```

and then you can compare this with  `R.drawable.starto` `.