# Get drawable of image button

Tags: android, android-drawable

How can I get the drawable of an Image Button to compare and do something if the drawable is A and something if is B?. Thank you so much.

```
    switch(getDrawableId(buttonRepeat)) {

        case R.drawable.a:
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

             break;
        case R.drawable.b:
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

             break;
        default:

        break;
          }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `getDrawable()` method in ImageButton and compare them using `.getConstantState().equals()`

Sample code:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImageBtn);
Drawable drawable = btn.getDrawable();
if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable).getConstantState())){
   //Do your work here
}
```

References:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

[Comparing two drawables in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android)