# What's the reverse of : SetBackgroundResouce?

Tags: android

As the question suggest, SetBackgroundResource is used if you want to set the background of an image button according to an image, such as:

```
p1Cards[n].SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.b1fv);
```

where b1fv is the image file.

Therefore my question is, what is the appropriate command to get the background image? For example, if I want to check whether an imagebutton is using this certain background  image, what is the command to use and check?

Comment: duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106904/get-drawable-of-image-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get drawable of image button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106904/get-drawable-of-image-button)