# What is Drawable.getConstantState used for?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I am using Drawable.getConstantState to compare two drawables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android) but couldnt understand its purpose. In the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getConstantState()), its given that

```
Return a Drawable.ConstantState instance that holds the shared state of this Drawable
```

Which shared state?

Also, Drawable.ConstantState

```
is used by Drawables to store shared constant state and data between Drawables
```

So i dont understand which shared state here and what data is stored? And how does it help in comparing the drawables.

Comment: read this:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html?m=1

Comment: @pskink thanks for the link.When we create 2 buttons, a different instance of drawable is created each time, so memory is being used here. How does sharing a common state between them saves memory?

Comment: ok,  buttons by default use NinePatchDrawable by default and this Drawable, in order to draw itself, uses NinePatch object, this object is relatively big as it holds a bitmap that will be drawn,  and even each Button's Drawable is a different NiniePatchDrawable but all of them point to the same NinePatch object

Comment: @pskink you saved my day.. you saved 2 of my days