# Comparing resources within two drawables

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare two drawables but without success. I did some research, there is even a similar question but did not help.

In my app, I use `getCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to get the ImageView in the right position of a EditText.
Then I need to check which image resource is alocated there.

This small sample should work, shouldn't it? It returns "not equal", though.

```
Drawable drawable1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.cor);

Drawable drawable2 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.cor);


if(drawable1 == drawable2){
     System.out.println("equal");
}else{
     System.out.println("not equal");
 }
```

Comment: You are applying these drawables on an ImageView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**getConstantState doesn't work well**

<s>If you do this: 
`if(drawable1 == drawable2){`</s>

you are comparing the reference of the objects and it not correct...

use instead equals with the `getConstantState()` method...

**Update** Try to compare with bytes or pixel is the only way that generally works.

```
 // Usage: 
 drawable1.bytesEqualTo(drawable2) 
 drawable1.pixelsEqualTo(drawable2) 
 bitmap1.bytesEqualTo(bitmap1) 
 bitmap1.pixelsEqualTo(bitmap2)
```

https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/3cca89416a1e443f914ed37f80ed59f2

Comment: I'll try that, even though I am not familiar with this method. What does it do exactly?

Comment: Tested this and it still has false positive cases for SVGs.