# How to compare two drawable images in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to compare drawable image with menu item icon.

**For example I want to like this**

```
if(item.getIcon().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.image))){
     ... 

}
```

but it doesn't work in android studio. How can I compare two drawable images?

Comment: You can not do such thing . You can compare `ids`. `#getIcon()` returns `Drawable` not `int`.

Comment: it won't work that way. But you can store which drawable you set to which item. If you don't do that in code, just use item ID to identify which item was clicked

Comment: I can solve this problem using Bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Do this way

```
 ConstantState constantStateDrawableA = drawableA.getConstantState();
ConstantState constantStateDrawableB = drawableB.getConstantState();

if(constantStateDrawableA.equals(constantStateDrawableB)) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare with bytes or pixel is the only way that generally works
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/36373569/8299619