# How to check that textbox's foreground is a certain image?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to check if a certain textbox's foreground matches a certain image and I tried the following but it did not work.

```
if(box.foreground == ContextCompat.getDrawable(box.context, R.drawable.image){
    //Do this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two different objects, so equals (== in Kotlin) will return false

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36373569/5624767)