# comparing src of ImageView with drawable in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, imageview

I am facing an issue while matching the `src` of `ImageView` with `drawable`. I am implementing this condition but it does not match:-

`if (ivServices.resources == ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.activity!!,R.drawable.un_check))`

Please help to solve this issue

Comment: can you please add more code and explain what is ivServices and ect?

Comment: ivServices is a reference of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

indication of duplicate

[Comparing resources within two drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373547/comparing-resources-within-two-drawables/36373569#36373569)

Comment: i think it is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373547/comparing-resources-within-two-drawables/36373569#36373569

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Cast it to Bitmap and compare it. The imageview and variables are different, keep in mind. It worked for me. It is written in Kotlin.

```
var bmap = Imgview.drawable.toBitmap()  
var myPic=getDrawable(R.drawable.jake_yellow_background_square)?.toBitmap()
        if(bmap.sameAs(myPic)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"It is WORKING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"It is NOT working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```