# How to switch icons of action bar menu in android

Tags: android, menu

I want to switch the icon in the actionbar on clicking to it.I did the following inside onOptionsItemSelected.

```
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.star_School:
            if (isStarFilled) {
                item.setIcon(R.mipmap.starfilled);
                isStarFilled=true;
            }else{
                item.setIcon(R.mipmap.star);
                isStarFilled=false;
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is not working in my case.This is my menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/star_School"
        android:icon="@mipmap/star"
        android:title="Bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

This is my onCreate Method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_details);
        Boolean isStarFilled=false;

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
```

cannot resolve symbol isStarFilled?
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your icons in drawable and compare some thing like this

```
 mRememberPwd.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
  (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_checked).getConstantState())
```

you can find more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android)  on how to compare drawable

you can also try using flag

global variable

```
boolean  isStarFilled=false;


case R.id.star_School:
            if (isStarFilled) {
                item.setIcon(R.mipmap.starfilled);
             isStarFilled=false;
            }else{
            item.setIcon(R.mipmap.star);
               isStarFilled=true;
               }
            return true;
```

Comment: variable isStarfilled is not connected to anywhere.How to initialize isStarFilled?

Comment: keep it on top of oncreate method

Comment: I have edited my question with latest code.Shows error inside if (isStarFilled)  cannot resolve symbol isStarFilled

Comment: keep  
    
        boolean isStarFilled=false;      


on top of oncreate, not inside oncreate method

Comment: I did as u said.It neither displays any error nor the icon is changed.

Comment: Thank you sir.Thank you so much.You have been very helpful.Can you do me a favour one more time?When i set the star to filled and come out of activity and again opened that activity star becomes blank again.I wish to remain as it is unless I change by myself?How can I do this?

Comment: if you want to save permanently what was your previous icon , use sharedpreferences to store what was your previous value of isstared and retrevie it back from this activity every time, do some research on how to store data in sharedpreferences and retriving it back, If my answer helped you please up vote it and consider accepting my answer by clicking tick mark beside my answer :)