# Drawable compare is always returning false after upgrading Huawei to emui 12

Tags: android, drawable, huawei-mobile-services

one of my customers detected a bug in my application after upgrading his Huawei to emui 12.
In the following, I'm checking if the imageView has `ic_correct_deactiviated` so that I will convert it to  ic_correct_activiated, the following always returns false in emui12, here is my code.

```
 if (checkCircleImageViewRecyclerViewLevelTwo.getDrawable().getConstantState()
                            .equals(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_correct_deactivated).getConstantState())) {
                                                 checkCircleImageViewRecyclerViewLevelTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_correct_activated);
```

Comment: You can try to convert your `Drawable` to Bitmap and use `convertedBitmap1.sameAs(convertedBitmap2)` or check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android