# Adding Bitmap a name

Tags: android, string, bitmap

When i convert bitmap to string with  `toString()` i get something like that: android.graphics.Bitmap@40da7c08. I want that name to be always the same so i can compare it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to extend the bitmap class and add another method to generate a unique identifier that you understand.

Comment: I have a list of bitmaps that a draw on canvas, those are four different bitmaps and i want to know which one has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is the default implementation of the `toString()` method in `Java`. Its basically the fully classified name of the class, followed by the `hexcode` of the object.

I would suggest that you do your comparison based on the `equals()` method or wrap your `Bitmap` objects inside a class of yours and add a name or id property.

Comment: so there is no way to change it boucase i want to compare that bitmap to another

Comment: do comparison using the .equals() method which checks if both the references are pointing to the same object, not necessarily that both object contains the same data.

Comment: @Itsmeyxc No you can't change it. You could override the `Bitmap` class yourself, however, and override the implementation of `toString()` to do a comparison on the pixels, something like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696320/321697) shows.