# Compare two canvas for differences

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Say i have a user painting a color on my canvas by dragging or tapping on the canvas. How could i check if the canvas was actually changed by this action.

i.e. if the user is painting with the color red and the area they dragged across is already red then the image will effectively be exactly the same. How can i compare the updated canvas image against the old canvas image to see if it actually changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the bitmaps that canvas is associated to. You can see several solutions for that in [Comparing Bitmap images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android)