# fetch image from image view from another activity

Tags: android

```
if( txt.equals("Apple"))
  {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Times up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
        ad.setMessage("You win");  
        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           @Override  
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
              dialog.dismiss();                      
            }  
        });

       ad.show(); 

  }
```

what should i write to compare Apple text with the image of imageview

Comment: Imagview img=new (Imageview)findviewbyid(R.id.fetchimage);

Comment: i also want it to use in IF Statement

Comment: @user3127549 use startActivity for result. But your post is not clear to me

Comment: @Raghunandan actually i want to compare the image of imageview with the text of edittext for example if i write Apple in edittext and there is also the picture of apple in the imageview only then success message should be pop out

Comment: if( txt.equals("Apple"))
   {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Times up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
      ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
      ad.setMessage("You win");  
      ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
         @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            dialog.dismiss();                      
          }  
      });
     
     ad.show(); 
      }
   WHAT SHOULD I WRITE CO COMPARE THE IMAGEVIEW IMAGE WITH EDITTEXT TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i see in your code, you are trying to `compare two drawables using equals method`. i don't think that is going to work.

to compare two `drawables`, one easy hack is to `convert them to bitmaps and check using ==`

```
Drawable fDraw = iv1.getDrawable();
Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mario_pinball);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)fDraw).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)sDraw).getBitmap();

if(bitmap == bitmap2)
    {
        //Code blcok
    }
```

EDIT : based on comment, if above method does not work

`Bitmap` class provides a method `sameAs()` to compare two Bitmaps
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29

EDIT:

based on OPs comments on the question, to compare text with image, you can [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) and [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29) in the image to store a text value, and then compare this value with the textview's text.

Comment: I would not count on those returning the same `Bitmap` object in all circumstances.

Comment: And your edit will be slow, as it has to iterate over all pixels for comparison purposes.

Comment: @CommonsWare please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android/7696320#7696320

Answer (score 1):

> what should i write to compare Apple text with the image of imageview

You wouldn't.

Instead, maintain some other data member that reflects what you put in the `ImageView` (e.g., an `int` of the `R.drawable` value) whenever you change the `ImageView`. Then, you can check that other data member for equality.