# For Android apps, how do I check what resource ID is being used in a specific image view?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-drawable, android-testing

I'm writing automated tests for my company's app. The tests use a combination of Espresso and Robotium. Several of those tests are supposed to check whether certain `ReactImageView` elements are displaying a specific image.

I first tried using `hasBackground()` as follows:

```
onView(...).check(matches(hasBackground(R.drawable...)));
```

However, this returns a `NoMatchingViewException`.

I then tried Daniele Bottillo's matcher as described here: https://medium.com/@dbottillo/android-ui-test-espresso-matcher-for-imageview-1a28c832626f

```
onView(allOf(..., new DrawableMatcher(R.drawable....), isDisplayed())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

But this didn't work either:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.drawee.generic.RootDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

Lastly, I tried Frankie Sardo's solution: [Android Espresso match BitmapDrawables with different tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902594/android-espresso-match-bitmapdrawables-with-different-tint)

```
onView(allOf(..., withImageDrawable(R.drawable...), isDisplayed())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

However, this again throws a `NoMatchingViewException`. I'm running out of ideas. Is it even possible to check what resource is attached to an image view?

Comment: "Is it even possible to check what resource is attached to an image view?" -- not really, since you can populate an `ImageView` from things other than a resource. In your case, you appear to be using an intermediate library (from Facebook) that is wrapping or otherwise manipulating your resource-based image.

Comment: Yeah, we're using React Native. I know it's possible to store the resource information using tags, but it's generally not considered a best practice to modify production code for QA purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use **[Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista)** library and its `assertHasDrawable(R.id.<imageview_id>, R.drawable.<drawable_id>)` assertion function.