# How to find similar object in two different images in android

Tags: android

For Example : if i have a rose in two different image. How to compare that rose irrespective of color, size and angle of view.

Refered different posts in stackoverflow but didnt get solution for what i am looking for.

Comment: please elaborate ,you question is not clear like are you getting images from server and loading images on App or you have some static images on app?

Comment: i have few source images , when i upload an image it should compare with all images in source images and if matches(similar image also like change in aspectratio,small in size , colour change) with any it shoud say match found.

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what are you trying to accomplish, but it looks like you need some image recognition to do. For example, this is the first result I get when i google "android image recognition" http://catchoom.com/documentation/image-recognition-sdk/android-image-recognition-sdk/ Maybe it could help.