# Convert byte[] to System.Drawing.Bitmap C# Xamarin.NET

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, emgucv

I'm trying to do a method that can convert a Emgu.Cv.Mat image into a System.Drawing.Bitmap image.

```
public Bitmap convertCvToBitmap(Mat img)
        {
            byte[] temp_img = this.convertCvToImage(img);
            Bitmap mp;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(temp_img))
            {
                mp = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
            return mp;
        }
```

Firstly I the convert Emgu.Cv.Mat image into a byte[] image, and then I convert this byte[] image into a System.Drawing.Bitmap image.

This method works on a desktop but doesn't when used in a Xamarin Android App, I've got this error: "**System.PlatformNotSupportedException:** 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'".

I know it's coming from this line of code: `mp = new Bitmap(ms);` (I checked it before using `Console.WriteLine`)

Can anyone knows the problem or if there is another path to convert an Emgu.Cv.Mat image into a System.Drawing.Bitmap image?

Thanks!

Comment: for a pixel-by-pixel comparison, use SkiaSharp

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Bitmap is not supported in Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS.

If you are going to display it on screen, then you need the Android variant of Bitmap and the iOS UIImage.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply !
I didn't know that. 
I use Bitmap to compare two images pixels by pixels using System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel(x, y) , do you know if I can use another image type to make this ?

Answer (score 0):

Android Bitmap also has the method [GetPixel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,%20int)) , just replace `System.Drawing.Bitmap` with `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` , and you need to do this in android platform (with dependency service).

```
public Android.Graphics.Bitmap convertCvToBitmap(Mat img)
{
   byte[] temp_img = this.convertCvToImage(img);
   Android.Graphics.Bitmap mp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(temp_img, 0, temp_img.Length);
   return mp;
}
```

Refer to

[Comparing Bitmap images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android)

[How to convert image file data in a byte array to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-image-file-data-in-a-byte-array-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: Did you solve the problem @Nathan Trouillet?